# How to use Azure API Management to publish a collection of endpoints for public partners and another for my own apps

Tags: azure-api-management

I'm looking to use Azure API Management (APIM) to publish my REST API endpoints to be consumed by external partner apps. I also have an app I own. I would like my app to consume the same endpoints as well as a few additional endpoints. I don't want to expose those additional endpoints to partner apps. Basically, I would like to end up with two packages of endpoints in APIM where I only expose the extra endpoints to my company's apps. My company's client apps are accessible over the Internet and are not isolated in an internal network.

This feels like a common use case, but I wasn't able to find anything directly addressing this. I'm assuming it's because I'm somewhat new to APIM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See Products: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-key-concepts#--products They're created specifically for the case of packaging same or different APIs into separate offerings. You can control product visibility as well, so that only users of specific group would be aware of some product, i.e. your own product can be made visible only to service administrators - you.